# Capture an Enter Key Pressed anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery

I need to capture an Enter Key press at any time anywhere on a logon page.
It will initiate a logon attempt.

Using jQuery, how would I accomplish this? And would I link it to the body tag?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
  }
});
```

Comment: I was trying this, which I noticed that keypress is not triggered for arrow keys but keydown is!

Comment: @akotian: Very true!  But, I like the earlier, fuller description of keypress vs. keydown from canoe's answer.

Answer (score 32):

The keydown event is fired when a key is pressed down.
The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value.

```
$(document).keydown( function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    // login code here
  }
});
```

Comment: This works better than `keypress`. For example I could get `keypress`  to detect when the ESC key was pressed. But `keydown` works perfectly. Thank you!