# MVC Html.BeginForm capture key press event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an MVC application, and I am using Html.BeginForm to make forms. There are several forms on the page, each representing a tab in a row of tabs. I need to detect the "Enter" key being pressed on one of the tabs. Anyone know how to do this?

Code example -

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm1" }))
{
    <div id="divId">
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's usually easiest to [use jQuery to handle that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery).

Comment: How exactly do you intent to capture the enter key on an element that does not accept keyboard input?

Comment: Mystere Man, I just want to detect that the "Enter" key has been pressed. An tie the running of a specific javascript to that action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture an Enter Key Pressed anywhere on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005162/capture-an-enter-key-pressed-anywhere-on-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ApplicationSchedule", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13" }))
```

You are able to add event listeners to the form using the htmlAttributes object parameter as I have done using the `new { onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13" }` section in the code. In my case I am ignoring the enter key when it is pressed in the form using the onkeydown listener. This is easily replaceable using your own code such as `onkeydown = "yourJavascriptFunction()"` to achive whatever it is you need to achieve when the enter key is pressed in the form. For more info on the parameters accepted for the Html.BeginForm(), see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)