# Pressing enter doesn't trigger button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that wen user presses enter in input button click is triggered, but I have problem that instead page is refreshed, I've tried several options found on SO but nothing helped, here is my code:

```
$("#phoneNumber").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {    
            event.preventDefault();   
            $("#request").click();

            }
        });

<div class="span12" id="numberDiv">
                <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Type a number" required="required" value="+385" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="request">Send</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button" id="terminate">Terminate</button>
            </div>
```

**EDIT**
I've tried all of your solutions but with no luck :/

Only thing that pops to mind that this piece of code could make problems (but not sure why)

```
 window.onload = function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#phoneNumber").on("focus", function() {
                if (this.setSelectionRange) {
                    var len = this.value.length * 2;
                    this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
                } else {
                    this.value = this.value;
                }
                this.scrollTop = 999999;
            }).focus();
        });
    };
```

Comment: use `keydown()` and `event.which` instead of `keyCode`

Comment: @yperN **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qKGC8/ **Behaviour** type something and hit the enter key. hpe it fits the need `:)` **Good link** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005162/jquery-capture-an-enter-key-pressed-anywhere-on-the-page

Comment: @Tats_innit please can you see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to initiate the `click` event on `#request` when an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed:

```
$("#phoneNumber").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#request").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest trying an overall function that is called on both the click() event and on the keypress event.

```
$("#phoneNumber").on('keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {    
            event.preventDefault();  
            doSomething();
        }
});

$("#request").click(function() {
            doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    //do something
}
```