# How to detect if a key is pressed anywhere on an HTML page?

Tags: html, onkeypress

Basically, I'm just trying to find a way to check if a key is pressed anywhere on an HTML page, then display a popup saying the key pressed. I've seen examples of doing this inside of a textfield, but I want this to happen no matter where you press the key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture an Enter Key Pressed anywhere on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005162/capture-an-enter-key-pressed-anywhere-on-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

Add this Javascript to your page

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', logAnyKey);

function logAnyKey() { 
  alert('key pressed'); 
}
```

This adds a listener to the complete document and alerts you when a key is pressed.